# In MAKE file : error showing no such file or directory

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have simple Makefile. When I run `make` I get following error:

```
gcc  -I -o server server.o comfunc.o

gcc: error: comfunc.o: No such file or directory

make: *** [server] Error 1
```

My Makefile:

```
 CC=gcc

 CFLAGS=-I

AIM = server

HEADS = ../common/common.h

OBJS = comfunc.o

MOBJ = server.o

MISCS = server.cfg

SRCS = ${OBJS:.o=.c} ${MOBJ:.o=.c}

#targets
all: $(AIM)


server:server.o

        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o server server.o $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

#dependency
$(OBJS):../common/common.h

comfunc.o: ../common/common.h

#--End of Makefile--
```

Comment: Shouldn't `server` depend on `$(OBJS)` (since it's trying to use them)?

Answer (score 1):

Add $(OBJS) and $(MOBJ) as dependency for server which will make sure the [implicit Makefile rules](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=implicit%20makefile%20rules) are executed which produces corresponding `.o`s

Refer the Makefile below

```
CC=gcc

 CFLAGS=-I

AIM = server

HEADS = ../common/common.h

OBJS = comfunc.o

MOBJ = server.o

MISCS = server.cfg

SRCS = ${OBJS:.o=.c} ${MOBJ:.o=.c}

#targets
all: $(AIM)


server:server.o $(OBJS) $(MOBJ)

        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -o server server.o $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

#dependency
$(OBJS):../common/common.h

comfunc.o: ../common/common.h
```